# Export Sketchflow prototype in an accessible way?

Tags: microsoft-expression

(I'm not sure if this is the correct Stack Exchange for this.)

I have a prototype I've built in Sketchflow. I would like to export it so people without Expression can see it. I don't have a webserver on which to host it. What options are available to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This video will tell you how to create a zip file with a viewer installed that you can distribute to anyone. http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/C01F